# XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log'?

Tags: ubuntu, logging, xdebug, php-7

XDebug could not open the remote debug file `/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log`.

I try to give permission 664 on the file `/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log` but failed what I do now.

Answer (score 1):

After I create the `/var/log/xdebug/` directory and create `xdebug.log` file and set permission to 777 everything pass very well

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/xdebug
sudo chmod 777 /var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log
```

Comment: Only worked for me when I chmoded the directory as well instead of just the file